# How does the author get rid of a constant $2$?

Tags: probability-theory, proof-explanation, weak-convergence

I'm reading a proof from Santambrogio's *Optimal Transport for Applied Mathematicians: Calculus of Variations, PDEs, and Modeling*

> **Lemma 1.31.** Consider on a compact metric space $X$, endowed with a probability $\rho \in \mathscr{P}(X)$, a sequence of partitions $G_{n}$, each $G_{n}$ being a family of disjoint subsets $C_{i, n}$ such that $\bigcup_{i \in I_{n}} C_{i, n}=X$ for every $n$. Suppose that $\operatorname{size}\left(G_{n}\right):=\max _{i} \operatorname{diam}\left(C_{i, n}\right)$ tends to 0 as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and consider a sequence of probability measures $\rho_{n}$ on $X$ such that, for every $n$ and $i \in I_{n}$, we have $\rho_{n}\left(C_{i, n}\right)=\rho\left(C_{i, n}\right)$. Then $\rho_{n} \rightarrow \rho$.

**Proof.** Set $m_{i, n}:=\rho_{n}\left(C_{i, n}\right)=\rho\left(C_{i, n}\right)$. It is sufficient to take a continuous function $\phi \in C(X)$ and note that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left|\int_{X} \phi \mathrm{d} \rho_{n}-\int_{X} \phi \mathrm{d} \rho\right| & \leq \sum_{i \in I_{n}}\left|\int_{C_{i, n}} \phi \mathrm{d} \rho_{n}-\int_{C_{i, n}} \phi \mathrm{d} \rho\right| \\
& \leq \omega\left(\operatorname{diam}\left(C_{i, n}\right)\right) \sum_{i \in I_{n}} m_{i, n}=\omega\left(\operatorname{diam}\left(C_{i, n}\right)\right) \rightarrow 0
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\omega$ is the modulus of continuity of $\phi$. This is justified by the fact that, whenever two measures have the same mass on a set $C \subset X$, since the oscillation of $\phi$ on the same set does not exceed $\omega(\operatorname{diam}(C))$, the difference of the two integrals is no more than this number times the common mass. This proves $\int \phi \mathrm{d} \rho_{n} \rightarrow \int \phi \mathrm{d} \rho$ and hence $\rho_{n} \rightarrow \rho$.

---

**My understanding:** We pick $x_{i,n} \in C_{i,n}$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\int_{C_{i, n}} \phi \mathrm{d} \rho_{n}-\int_{C_{i, n}} \phi \mathrm{d} \rho\right| &= \left|\int_{C_{i, n}} [\phi - \phi(x_{i,n})] \mathrm{d} \rho_{n} - \int_{C_{i, n}} [\phi - \phi(x_{i,n})] \mathrm{d} \rho\right| \\
&\le \int_{C_{i, n}} |\phi - \phi(x_{i,n})| \mathrm{d} \rho_{n} + \int_{C_{i, n}} |\phi - \phi(x_{i,n})| \mathrm{d} \rho \\
&\le \int_{C_{i, n}}\omega (\operatorname{diam}\left(C_{i, n}\right)) \mathrm{d}  \rho_{n} +  \int_{C_{i, n}} \omega (\operatorname{diam}\left(C_{i, n}\right)) \mathrm{d}  \rho \\
&= 2  \omega (\operatorname{diam}\left(C_{i, n}\right)) m_{i,n}.
\end{align}
$$

Could you please explain how the author gets rid of a constant $2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about taking $x_{i,n}$ which satisfies $\phi(x_{i,n})=\inf_{x\in C_{i,n}}\phi(x)$. The existence of that follows from compactness of $X$ and continuity of $\phi$. $x_{i,n}$ may not belong to $C_{i,n}$ but we still have

$0\leq\phi(y)-\phi(x_{i,n})\leq \omega(diam(C_{i,n}))$ for $y\in C_{i,n}$. Now the result follows since $|A-B|\leq\max(A,B)$ for $A>0,B>0$.

Take $A = \int_{C_{i,n}}(\phi(x)-\phi(x_{i_n})d\rho$ and $B = \int_{C_{i,n}}(\phi(x)-\phi(x_{i_n})d\rho_{n}$. Note that $\max(A,B)\leq \omega(diam(C_{i,n}))*m_{i,n}$

Comment: If $x_{i, n} \notin C_{i, n}$, how do we have $0\leq\phi(y)-\phi(x_{i,n})\leq \omega(diam(C_{i,n}))$?

Comment: $\phi(y)- \phi(x_{i,n}) = \sup_{x\in C_{i,n}}  (\phi(y)-\phi(x))$. Does that make sense?

Comment: Could you explain how $|A-B|\leq\max(A,B)$ helps us get rid of the constant $2$? IMHO, you still have $2$ sums.

Comment: see  my new edits

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Now I got it.

Comment: Great. Thanks for accepting my answer. I am new here